# Expectation of reaching state from transition matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Consider the transition matrix $p_{xy}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &0&0\\0.5 & 0 &0.5&0\\0&0.5&0&0.5\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

> My question though is how to determine the **expectation of the first visiting time of the Markov chain of states 1 or 4 from each state**, $E(\tau)$.

For states $x=1,4$, it is clear that $E(\tau)=1 $ since it is already there. However for $x=2$ and $3$, it is a little more complicated.

Now I know, $P(X_t ~ \text{visits 1 from 2 any time})= P(X_t ~ \text{visits 4 from 2 any time})=\frac{1}{3}.$

So, when $x=2, E(\tau) = \sum_{t=1}t\mathbb{P}(X_t ~ \text{visits 1 or 4 first}) = ...$ supposedly the solution is 2, but i cannot see how to get this?

[image]

Comment: Presumably you mean that both $1$ and $4$ are recurrent states

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "$P(X_t ~ \text{visits 1 from 2 any time})$"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i.e. the probability that $X$ reaches at some moment the state $1$ starting from $x=2$. There are 3 possible states that can be reached from state 2, so it's clear to find the probability.

Comment: It sounds like there are $3$ mutually exclusive events that you have assumed are of equal probability. What are these $3$ events, and why can we assume that they are equally likely?

Comment: The probability of moving from the state $2$ finally to state $1$ is $2/3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows.  Given that $X_0 = 2$, the probability for a fixed time $t$ that we land on either $1$ or $4$ for the first time is $(1/2)^t$. With that, we find that the expected time until landing on either $1$ or $4$ is
$$
E(\tau) = \sum_{t=1}^\infty t \cdot (1/2)^{t} = 2,
$$
which was what we wanted.